# How to disable generation of Test Javadoc report in Maven 3 site plugin?

Tags: java, maven, maven-3, maven-site-plugin

This is my `pom.xml`, I'm trying to disable `Test Javadoc` report in `site`:

```
[...]
<build>
  [...]
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-site-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
      <reportPlugins>
        [...]
        <plugin>
          <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
          <artifactId>maven-javadoc-plugin</artifactId>
          <configuration>
            <reportSets>
              <reportSet>
                <id>html</id>
                <reports>
                  <report>javadoc</report>
                </reports>
              </reportSet>
            <reportSet>
          </configuration>
        </plugin>
      </reportPlugins>
    </configuration>
  </plugin>
</build>
```

Still Maven3 generates both `Javadoc` and `Test Javadoc` reports in the site. How to fix it?

Answer (score 2):

This works correctly for me as documented in [Selective Javadocs reports](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-javadoc-plugin/examples/selective-javadocs-report.html).  Can you re-check the versions of the plugins that you are using?   With the snippet below and running `mvn site` using Maven 3.0.1, only `Javadoc` gets generated. Adding the line `<report>test-javadoc</report>` below the existing `<report>` tag results in both `Javadoc` and `Test Javadoc` getting generated.

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-site-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.0-beta-3</version>
            <configuration>
                <reportPlugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                        <artifactId>maven-javadoc-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>2.7</version>
                        <reportSets>
                            <reportSet>
                                <id>html</id>
                                <reports>
                                    <report>javadoc</report>
                                </reports>
                            </reportSet>
                        </reportSets>
                    </plugin>
                  </reportPlugins>
              </configuration>
          </plugin>
```

Comment: Hm.. I double checked all versions. It's `Maven:3.0`, `maven-site-plugin:3.0-beta-3` and `maven-javadoc-plugin:2.7` (the same as in your example). I still keep getting two reports... Very strange, I will investigate further.

Comment: FYI - This solution worked for me, with 'maven-site-plugin' version 3.0 and 'maven-javadoc-plugin' version 2.8