# How to link source classes JavaDoc from Test JavaDoc in maven site?

Tags: maven, javadoc, maven-site-plugin, maven-javadoc-plugin

Having configured maven-site-plugin and maven-javadoc-plugin (with [doclava doclet](http://code.google.com/p/doclava/)), I'm trying to get proper JavaDocs on the site generated by `mvn site`.  In my code I have sevaral JUnit test classes (located in *src/test/java/my/package/*.java*) which JavaDoc comments link the source classes (located in *src/main/java/my/package/*.java*).  The problem is that when generating Test JavaDocs, javadoc cannot find where source classes documentation is located.  I tried to tell javadoc where to find it by using `links` and `offlineLinks` configuration options of maven-javadoc-plugin ([documented here](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-javadoc-plugin/examples/links-configuration.html)), but with no luck.  I'd like javadoc to generate relative links so that they are workable when viewing generated documentation offline (browsing from */path/to/project/target/site/index.html* in a browser).  I wouldn't like to [disable Test JavaDocs generation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4544322/)

[My pom.xml](http://pastie.org/2484113) | [An excerpt from mvn site output](http://pastie.org/2484131)

Also, I'm a Java and Maven newbie

---

To clarify the question, here is an example.  I have a test class `GenerateATest` residing in *src/test/java/name/earshinov/PrefixCircuits/GenerateATest.java* (sorry that comments are in Russian):

```
package name.earshinov.PrefixCircuits;
// imports skipped

/**
 * Тестирование алгоритма построения вспомогательных подсетей типа A,
 * реализованного в классе {@link name.earshinov.util.PrefixCircuitGenerator},
 * по отдельным случаям, описанным в оригинальной статье
 */
public class GenerateATest {
// ...
```

The linked class `PrefixCircuitGenerator` is in *src/main/java/name/earshinov/PrefixCircuits/PrefixCircuitGenerator.java*.  After I run `mvn site`, I get JavaDocs for source classes at *target/site/apidocs/index.html* and Test JavaDocs at *target/site/testapidocs/index.html*.  In `GenerateATest` documentation in Test JavaDocs I'd like to see the link leading to the documentation of `PrefixCircuitGenerator` in source classes JavaDocs.  However, javadoc can't find `PrefixCircuitGenerator` I refer to, so it does not generate the link and the corresponding warning is visible in `mvn site` output:

```
[WARNING] /home/eugene/dev/java/PrefixCircuits-maven/src/test/java/name/earshinov/PrefixCircuits/GenerateATest.java:9: warning 101: Unresolved link/see tag "name.earshinov.util.PrefixCircuitGenerator" in name.earshinov.PrefixCircuits.GenerateATest
```

My aim is to (somehow) tell javadoc how to generate the link.  Changing `{@link name.earshinov.PrefixCircuits.PrefixCircuitGenerator}` to `{@link PrefixCircuitGenerator}` does not change anything.

Comment: First i would suggest to clean up your build to prevent any warnings during the site generation as stated in the output. Furthermore what kind of links don't work? Links to production code?

Comment: @khmarbaise What do you mean by cleaning up the build? I get the same warnings after `mvn clean`.  Regarding the links I need, I'll add an example to the topic

Comment: You get warnings about the maven-project-info-report-plugin cause you didn't define the version number of the maven-project-info-report-plugin in your build.

Comment: @khmarbaise I did not use this plugin explicitly (it is probably a dependency of the site-plugin), so I did not want to include it in my POM only to define its version.  Now I added the project-info-report-plugin to the list of the reporting plugins as, I assume, you recommend

Comment: You can tell javadoc where documentation for related classes is by using the `-link` parameter. I have no idea how this transfers to Maven, though.

Comment: @Paŭlo The `-link` parameter is controlled by the `links` configuration option of the javadoc plugin. I tried it without successs. It can be that I tried it in a wrong way, but we need a Maven or Maven&JavaDoc expert here

Answer (score 0):

Just got some time for experimentation.  Seems that doclava doclet just does not support foreign documentation links (does not implement `-link` command line option).  I discovered it by running javadoc from CLI.  Probably javadoc plugin knows that the `-link` option is specific to the standard doclet, so it does not bother getting the value of this option from pom.xml and passing it to javadoc via command line arguments, if an alternative doclet is used.  Hence no error is generated.